TexLive Installation Windows
I have a little problem
I have reinstalled my laptop and only installed Perl Strawberry. It is a completely clean Windows 10 and I am now trying to install TexLive. However, I always get the error which roughly translates to:

“.” cannot be processed syntactically at this point

The error appears directly after executing the exe during unpacking.
In the Installation it looks like this:

I have already tried to unpack and start the bat manually or with administrator.
Nothing works.
I have to say that I am more of a layman in this area and therefore don't really know how to proceed
Thanks for the help

So actually I'm just stupid. I have always rebooted the laptop via the internal Lenovo system. What I didn't realize is that Lenovo then installs a really old Windows version. This was no longer supported by TexLive. I have now downloaded a current version of Windows onto a stick and installed it. TexLive now runs without any problems. So the error no longer exists :)
